# Free PDF editing software which doesn't destroy the TOC

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, adobe-reader

I created a pretty huge document (> 100 pages) in LibreOffice Writer which I exported as PDF. When I open this PDF in Acrobat Reader and click on one of the TOC entries Acrobat jumps to the corressponding page. Now I want to add some layouts I created with ArcMap to my document. Since importing EMF or SVG exported from ArcMap isn't working very well in Writer I decided to export the layouts as PDF and use a third party tool to merge the PDFs. I already tried PDFtk and PDFsam. PDFsam creates a nice looking PDF which also isn't bigger in filesize as the summed up filesizes of the separate documents (PDFtk output also looks nice but filesize is out of scale). The downside of both tools is, that the PDFs TOC isn't working for pages after the first inserted layout. I also tried inserting place holder pages in the Writer document and exchanging them with the desired layout in PDFsam but this didn't change anything.

**Is there any free tool available, which can add pages to a PDF without destroying it's TOC?**

Comment: Your question is off-topic because it is asking for a product recommendation. You can find what is [on-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for this site in the [help]. You may also want to take a look at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is there a way how I can move my question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com in one step?

Comment: Other than copy & paste, not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF merge in PDFsam does keep the outline (bookmarks) in order, if that's what you mean with ToC. If you are talking about a summary at the beginning of the document with clickable links, that should also be working after the merge.
I suggest you to open an issue [here](https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam/issues) attaching the files and we will take a look and fix it if it's an issue with PDFsam.

Comment: Done that: https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam/issues/206